# Kafka topics beyond retention period

Tags: apache-kafka

What happens to topics that are beyond their retention period? The messages will get wiped out but will the topic still exist and if so, will it write to offset 0 if there is only one partition on a topic?

Answer (score 2):

Each offset within a partition is always assigned to a single message, and it won't be reassigned. From [Log Compaction Basics](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_compactionbasics) documentation:

> Note that the messages in the tail of the log retain the original offset assigned when they were first written—that never changes. Note also that all offsets remain valid positions in the log, even if the message with that offset has been compacted away ...

Answer (score 1):

The brokers will hold no data for those topics, but the offsets will be set at their "high water mark" until new messages are produced.

The topic metadata will still exist, and the offsets always increase, never reset.